# PHP include and require not working in ubuntu even after setting the include_path

Tags: php, ubuntu, include, include-path

Below is my include path as shown by `phpinfo()`

```
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/html/WebPHP
```

There is a page in `/var/www/html/WebPHP/frags` dir that I want to include in my index.php.

But nothing works.

What I am doing wrong?

**Edit**

```
    <?php
        set_include_path("/var/www/html/WebPHP/frags");
        ini_set('include_path', '/var/www/html/WebPHP/frags')
        include 'frags/GuestHeader.php';
        echo phpinfo();
    ?>
```

Comment: Try ini_set('include_path', '/var/www/html/WebPHP/frags/') instead of set_include_path('/var/www/html/WebPHP/frags') . Does that  make a difference?

Comment: Tried this, still not working

Comment: Can you make an edit and post the code that you are using for the include path? Also try holding the return value in a variable and what does the return value say?

Comment: Did you check permissions in this directory?

Comment: @Sal00m: Yes I have changed the permissions(by adding current user as an owner) too for the directory and the included php file.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to include one specific file, you should add in your index.php file :

```
require_once '/path/to/your/file.php';
```

However, if your really want to include the whole directory, you can do :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/your/directory');
```

Edit : if it still doesn't work, you can do something like :

```
foreach (glob("/your/directory/*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
}
```

Comment: As I have several things in that dir to include, I am using the `set_include_path` method here, but no luck.